# How is verbatim implemented?

Tags: tex-core, verbatim

I'm curious as to how verbatim is implemented internally in TeX. I am mostly familiar with the basics of TeX's inner mechanics (catcodes, and what not), but I'm just curious about this command.

Comment: If you're in a hurry before someone answers: see `texdoc source2e` for the implementation (with documentation) of the verbatim environment. It's just 3 pages and a bit.

Comment: I think you might want to elaborate a bit whether you mean 'How verbatim-like environments may be implemented in general' or 'How a specific `\verbatim` command works'. The two answers posted at present take different lines on what you mean in this regard: the [tag:tex-core] suggests you mean the very general case but it's not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example

```
\beginverbatim
 verbatim text & $ #
 in more    lines... 
\endverbatim
```

can be implemented as

```
\def\beginverbatim{\par
   \begingroup
      ... set all special catcodes to other
      ... set space as active and define it as \space
      ... set ^^M as active and define it as \par
      \beginverbatimA
}
\def\beginverbatimA #1<tricky of \endverbatim separator>{%
    #1%
    \endgroup % restores normal catcodes
}
```

Of course, this is only pseudocode. We need to define `\beginverbatimA` with parameter `#1` separated by `\endverbatim` where this separator uses `\` as normal character with catcode "other". It needs some "tricky" code. For example, like this:

```
\let\ea=\expandafter
\ea\def\ea\beginverbatimA\ea#\ea1\string\endverbatim{%
    #1\endgroup
}
```

The main idea is presented here, not the whole implementation.

**Edit:** A LaTeX-notice: second answer here specializes to LaTeX but one thing is missed there: how the `\@xverbatim` works and how it is implemented. This is analogue to `\endverbatimA` mentioned in my answer, but the separator of `#1` parameter must be `\end{verbatim}` where not only `\` but above that the `{` and `}` must have catcode "other". This can be done, for example by:

```
\let\ea=\expandafter
\edef\tmp{\string\end\string{verbatim\string}}
\ea\def\ea\@xverbatim\ea#\ea1\tmp{#1\end{verbatim}}
```

but you can see in `latex.ltx` that another approach was used here.

Answer (score 20):

Let's begin with an excerpt from `latex.ltx` (the LaTeX "kernel"):

```
\def\verbatim{\@verbatim \frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces \@xverbatim}
\def\endverbatim{\if@newlist \leavevmode\fi\endtrivlist}
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}
```

The instruction `\@verbatim` does most of the heavy lifting. It is defined as follows (also in `latex.ltx`, right before `\def\verbatim...`):

```
\def\@verbatim{\trivlist \item\relax
  \if@minipage\else\vskip\parskip\fi
  \leftskip\@totalleftmargin\rightskip\z@skip
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\@flushglue\parskip\z@skip
  \@@par
  \language\l@nohyphenation
  \@tempswafalse
  \def\par{%
    \if@tempswa
      \leavevmode \null \@@par\penalty\interlinepenalty
    \else
      \@tempswatrue
      \ifhmode\@@par\penalty\interlinepenalty\fi
    \fi}%
  \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
  \obeylines \verbatim@font \@noligs
  \everypar \expandafter{\the\everypar \unpenalty}%
}
```

There's a lot going on, isn't there? The most important instructions are as follows. First, LaTeX enters a `trivlist` environment (which will be terminated by `\endtrivlist`, at the end of `\endverbatim`). Unless we're in a `minipage` environment, a vertical skip in the amount of `\parskip` is performed. After executing a paragraph break (via `\@@par`) and suppressing all hyphenation, `\par` is redefined locally. The single most important set of instructions is `let\do\@makeother \dospecials`. They set the catcodes of `\` (space), `\` (backslash), `{`, `}`, `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, `%`, and `~` to "other" (12). Essentially, all TeX-special characters are not special inside a `verbatim` environment. Next, TeX is instructed to obey line breaks, switch the font to monospaced (aka "teletype" or `tt`), and activate some characters in order to break ligatures such as `<<` for `«`. The standard paragraph-builder penalty for line breaks is unset. Wow -- we've made it to the end of the `\@verbatim` code block.

Next, `\frenchspacing` (a plain-TeX command that's replicated in the LaTeX kernel) ensures that no extra space is inserted after punctuation marks. In comparison, the chores handled by `\endverbatim` are nearly trivial: The most important instruction is `\endtrivlist`, which closes the `trivlist` environment that was opened at the start of `\@verbatim`.

The `trivlist` environment is a very important tool in LaTeX. It occurs quite a few times in `latex.ltx`. For example, the `center`, `flushleft`, `flushright` environments are all set up as trivlists, and the `list` environment employs `trivlist` internally. The `enumerate`, `itemize`, and `description` environments employ `list` environments internally and thus, ultimately, `trivlist` environments as well.

Comment: The question was not LaTeX specific but this answer is LaTeX specific. IMHO, it is better (almost everytime) to do the implementation from scratch than to be inspired by LaTeX code.

Comment: @wipet - It’s true that I interpreted the question about how `verbatim` works to be related to the LaTeX environment called `verbatim`. If that’s not what the OP had in mind, I trust I’ll get a comment to that effect.

Comment: `\@noligs` is not about `ff`, `fi` and so on. Its job is to activate some characters in order to break ligatures such as ``?` `` for ¿ or `<<` for «.

Comment: @egreg - I stand corrected! I'll edit the passage in question to incorporate your information.