# How the verbatim environment of LaTeX works exactly with a simple, clear example

Tags: verbatim

As I am a beginner of learning the TeX and LaTeX internal mechanism, I tried to find some information about the verbatim environment and how it is handle by LaTeX.
For example, if we have this command

```
\begin{verbatim}

ijdjdjda634&%

\end{verbatim}
```

How does TeX executes it? Primitive control sequences are directly executed by TeX 's stomach, right? Is it possible to write me exactly the steps of the process? Thanks!

Comment: it isn't clear exactly what you mean. for example the vast majority of the processing is exactly the same as if you had used `\texttt{ijdjdjda634\&\%}` just a little bit at the start to make `&` and `%` act like normal characters. Do you want the processing of the standard typesetting of that text to be described?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I want to understand the exact steps when TeX scans the the control sequence \begin{verbatim} and how the \begin{verbatim} works!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412939/how-is-verbatim-implemented perhaps?

Comment: @JosephWright oh I'd made an example but looks like a duplicate to me so won't post:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle another example will be helpful to understand it better as in the other post is not so clear to me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LaTeX enters the verbatim environment and terminates at the end of \end{verbatim}. Then, the characters inside the verbatim environment are executed without being interpreted and the category codes are set to 12. Is that the process? The examples given in the above post is not so clear to me as I am a beginner.

Comment: @KathrineHanson yes more or less (but it's hard to imagine why a beginner would ever need to know anything about this:-) It's not a question answerable as a beginner question (catcodes for example don't really get a mention at all in the whole of the latexbook)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and TeX reacts the same when it scans the primitive command \begin{verbatim} as with \def? I am just interested in the verbatim environment as the resources are not so clear to me!

Comment: `\def` is a tex primitive and `\begin` is a macro defined by latex so no, `\begin{verbatim}` calls `\verbatim` that sets the catcodes of special characters to 12 as outlined by wipet in the answer in the duplicate question. If you want the full details `texdoc source2e` will give you the documented source.